# ssh2_connect(): error starting up ssh connection(-5): unable to exchange encryption keys + centos 7 + php7.4

Tags: php, centos, php-7.4, libssh2, ssh2

while connect my destination server by

```
ssh2_connect("<<server-ip>>", 22)
```

then received error

> ssh2_connect(): error starting up ssh connection(-5): unable to exchange encryption keys

- PHP version 7.4.29
- OS version CentOs Linux 7

ssh2 extention and lib2ssh 1.8.0 already installed

[image]

how to resolve this issue?

Does any library need to be added or updated?